# Sql Server 2008 r2 Using a WHILE loop inside a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, loops, while-loop

I read an answer that said you don't want to use `WHILE` loops in SQL Server.  I don't understand that generalization.  I'm fairly new to SQL so I might not understand the explanation yet.  I also read that you don't really want to use cursors unless you must.  The search results I've found are too specific to the problem presented and I couldn't glean useful technique from them, so I present this to you.

What I'm trying to do is take the values in a client file and shorten them where necessary.  There are a couple of things that need to be achieved here.  I can't simply hack the field values provided.  My company has standard abbreviations that are to be used.  I have put these in a table, Abbreviations. the table has the `LongName` and the `ShortName`. I don't want to simply abbreviate every `LongName` in the row.  I only want to apply the update as long as the field length is too long.  This is why I need the `WHILE` loop.

My thought process was thus:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ScrubAbbrev]
(@Field nvarchar(25),@Abbrev nvarchar(255))
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @max int = (select MAX(stepid) from Abbreviations)
    DECLARE @StepID int = (select min(stepid) from Abbreviations)
    DECLARE @find varchar(150)=(select Longname from Abbreviations where Stepid=@stepid)
    DECLARE @replace varchar(150)=(select ShortName from Abbreviations where Stepid=@stepid)
    DECLARE @size int = (select max_input_length from FieldDefinitions where FieldName = 'title')
    DECLARE @isDone int = (select COUNT(*) from SizeTest where LEN(Title)>(@size))

    WHILE @StepID<=@max or @isDone = 0 and LEN(@Abbrev)>(@size) and @Abbrev is not null
    BEGIN
        RETURN
        REPLACE(@Abbrev,@find,@replace)
        SET @StepID=@StepID+1
        SET @find =(select Longname from Abbreviations where Stepid=@stepid)
        SET @replace =(select ShortName from Abbreviations where Stepid=@stepid)
        SET @isDone = (select COUNT(*) from SizeTest where LEN(Title)>(@size))
    END
END
```

Obviously the `RETURN` should go at the end, but I need to reset the my variables to the next `@stepID`, `@find`, and `@replace`.

Is this one of those times where I'd have to use a cursor (which I've never yet written)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't want to use cursors or while loops in SQL because they only process a single row at a time, and thus perform very poorly. SQL is designed and optimized to process (potentially very large) *sets* of data, not individual values.

You could factor out the while loop by doing something like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.targetColumn = a.ShortName
FROM targetTable t
INNER JOIN Abbreviations a
ON t.targetColumn = a.LongName
WHERE LEN(t.targetColumn) > @maxLength
```

This is generalized and you will need to tweak it to fit your specific data model, but here's what's going on:

For every row in "targetTable", set the value of "targetColumn" (what you want to abbreviate) to the relevant abbreviation (found in Abbreviations.ShortName) iff: the current value has a standardized abbreviation (the inner join) and the current value is longer than desired (the where condition).

You'll need to add an integer parameter or local variable, @maxLength, to indicate what constitutes "too long". This query processes the target table all at once, updating the value in the target column for every eligible row, while a function will only find the abbreviation for a single item (the intersection of one row and one column) at a time.

Note that this won't do anything if the value is too long but doesn't have a standard abbreviation. Your existing code has this same limitation, so I assume this is desired behavior.

I also recommend making this a stored procedure rather than a function. Functions on SQL Server are treated as black boxes and can seriously harm performance, because the optimizer generally doesn't have a good idea of what they're doing.

Comment: I see what you're saying as anything that has to evaluate each line would be a weighty process. This is contact information, so I would have to apply it to each field based on it's available length.  Also, I can't replace the entire field.

What I'm look at achieving is transforming "Research Associate Professor of Biostatistics" into "Prof, Dept Pathology & Lab Medicine, UBC"  That's why I'm using the `REPLACE`function, not `SET`.

Comment: Sure, makes sense. Looks like you might have more than one abbreviation per entry as well. In this case you'd want to join on targetColumn like '%'+LongName+'%', and use replace in the update statement. Might need some tweaks to ensure avoiding false positives (e.g. partial word matches), but the general technique is the same: use a set based approach to avoid the performance troubles of loops.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll revisit this project next week. Apparently I can't upvote yet.  :-/

Comment: Cheers. You'll be able to upvote once you've gathered a small amount of reputation. You can do so by getting upvotes on your questions and answers, accepting an answer, or making edits on others' posts (but only if necessary - your edits will be reviewed by others and must be approved).